# Calculating Big O Complexity

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

On a recent exam, we were given a function to count how many doubles (not the primitive `double`, but how many times an item appears twice) appear in an unsorted ArrayList.

I correctly determined that the Big O complexity was O(N^2), but was only given partial credit because I incorrectly determined the full complexity. The function was as follows:

```
public static <T> int countDoubles(ArrayList<T> list, int index, Comparator<? super T> cmp) {
    if (index >= list.size())
        return 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = index + 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (cmp.compare(list.get(index), list.get(i)) == 0)
            count++;
    }
    return count + countDoubles(list, index + 1, cmp);
}
```

In the exam solution he just released, he gave this explaination:

> There are N items in the input collection, and the method calls itself
>   over and over with a reduction step that produces a new index N times
>   till it reaches the base case (end of the collection). For each
>   recursive frame there is a for loop that work on one less element in
>   the collection in each frame repeatedly until it reaches the end of
>   the collection. So there are N recursive calls and N -1 steps for the
>   first call, N-2 for the second, N-3 for the third and so on, until the
>   end of the array is reached. This behavior has a quadratic growth in
>   terms of the upper bound complexity as it will present the following
>   expression:
>
> T(N) = (N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) + ... + 1 = N(N-1)/2 = ((N^2)/2) - (N/2)
>   = O(N^2)

In attempt to correctly understand this I attempted to draw out a simple array of size ten, reducing its examined size by one every time.

```
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
   [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
      [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
         [] [] [] [] [] [] []
            [] [] [] [] [] []
               [] [] [] [] []
                  [] [] [] []
                     [] [] []
                        [] []
                           []
```

Counting the levels of recursion makes sense as `N`. Counting each element out yields that 9 + 8 ... = 45 Considering that 100 (N levels of recursion * N elements) is 100, I do not understand where `N/2` comes from, let alone `((N^2)/2) - (N/2)`.

Any explaination is much appreciated, as I have been looking for the past month and can't seem to fully grasp what I'm missing. Thank you.

Comment: Try to read about  the [Master Theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the integers from `1` to `M` is `((M+1) * M) / 2`. That's just a mathematical fact (typically proven by induction).  Try some examples if you aren't convinced.

The first pass through the algorithm does `N-1` `compare`s, and each level of recursion does one less `compare`, until the last level of recursion does 1 `compare`. So the total number of compares (for all levels of recursion) is the sum of the integers from `1` to `N-1`. Substituting `N-1` for `M` in the formula gives the total number of compares as `(N * (N-1)) / 2`.

From there, it's just algebra

```
(N * (N-1)) / 2 = (N * N - N) / 2 = ((N^2) / 2) - (N / 2)
```

The reason for breaking it down that way is because big-O only cares about the `N` with the largest exponent. Of course, big-O also doesn't care about constants.  So you throw away the `(N / 2)` and you ignore the `/ 2` and the answer is O(*N^2*), which is the biggest crock o' ...

Well, never mind my opinion on the matter, that's just the way it is.

Comment: Ooohhhkay. I think I understand much more now. My math was partially wrong, because I wasn't including `M`, which is 10. I stopped short at 45 when it should have been 55. Additionally, I wasn't even aware of the equation `((M+1) * M) / 2` being used in this situation to sum these up (I was misunderstanding and thinking it was just half of the N^2, which was completely wrong). After that the algebra makes complete sense! Thanks a TON!

Comment: Yup, that formula should come in handy at least a few times in your programming career, so it's a good one to know :)